# Instantiating class by string in current namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm trying to instantiate an object of a dynamically created classname.
I'm using namespaces and the class I want to instantiate is in the same namespace.

To examplify, this works fine:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

new MyClass; // MyNamespace\MyClass instantiated
```

Whereas this doesn't:

```
namespace MyNamespace;

$class = 'MyClass';
new $class; // Class 'MyClass' not found
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use a string with `new` you need to provide a fully qualified class name.

You can do this with `__NAMESPACE__`:

```
$fullclass = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $class;
new $fullclass;
```

See the documentation for the [`new` operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) and the [`__NAMESPACE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant.

Comment: Hi, looks valid. Could you link to your source for reference? Thanks :-)

Comment: Nice, thanks for the links. But I'm now wondering, when you say "fully qualified class name", shouldn't it start with '\' too? Maybe the leading '\' can be implied in cases like this?

Comment: Another thing, though your answer is valid, the actual code throws a syntax error because of the concatenating, I guess. Assign the qualified name in advance to a variable and it should work.

Comment: Is all about with the order of the class load, explanation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)

Comment: @jgivoni OK, corrected. The leading `\\` only says "this is a fully-qualified class name"; it isn't part of that classname.

Comment: @lonesomeday Ok, there is a subtle difference there :-) Thanks for sharing.